# How to override Woocommerce Single Product template page in child-theme?

Tags: wordpress, layout

I have a problem with my theme and I am sick of tired to communicate with the theme support team...so I try to solve the issue myself (if possible).
My problem is: I have some single product layout under theme option but when I try to change none of them work. I could overwrite the style in the child theme (how the information, text...etc will show) but my main problem is the product image. Is it too big and the thumbs appear under the image. I want smaller image box and thumbs on the left side. Is it possible to overwrite this in the child theme somehow?
I am not a professional programmer or web designer, but would be happy to learn :)
Thanks for any help or comments :)

Answer (score 2):

May be you can check it with word press plugins. Here is a [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tp-woocommerce-product-gallery/). Before override Woo commerce Single Product Template You can try it with custom css in your theme style.css

Copy this very basic CSS and place in your child theme’s style.css file. Check this [link](https://divijungle.com/display-woocommerce-product-gallery-vertically/).

Comment: Thanks Sanket, it is very helpful! Appreciate it!